# REST API get method not gives the result

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to fetch the record from the REST API ,
I wan to fetch that record on the textbox ng-blur event,

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="text ng-blur="dataTest()"   name="id" placeholder="Enter id Number" ng-model="id">
</div>

$http.get('http://192.168.0.103/api/home/Get_OneTime_Info/?User_ID=' +$scope.Id).
            success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.Details = data.User_OneTime; //GetAllBolck is the API service name and teh Table is the object name of that api. 
                alert('Success');
            }).
        error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            alert("error");
```

but when i send the static data to this service then it fetch the record.

Comment: If you put 'http://192.168.0.103/api/home/Get_OneTime_Info/?User_ID= in your browser, does the API send back what you expect? If so, that would help us liit this issue to an AngularJS implementation problem.

Comment: 192.168.0.103/api/home/Get_OneTime_Info/?User_ID=1  Yes when i send this to the browser i ll get the result, but then i pass id using the the textbox then i can's give the result, i want the help to  fetch if when i enter id in text box and then i get the result.

Comment: The question is 'does that route return the data you want when you call it in a browser?'

Comment: yes, i am also call this function...   $scope.dataTest = function () {
        var data = $.param({
            User_ID: $scope.pincode

        });
        $http.get('http://192.168.0.103/api/home/Get_OneTime_Info/?User_ID=' +$scope.Id).
            success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.Details = data.User_OneTime;  
                alert('Log in Success');
            }).
        error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            alert("error");
            
        });

Comment: You have the ng-model set to "id" while in your function you are using $scope.Id. Try using $scope.id and see if it gives you the correct id. You're also missing a closing " on your type="text. If these don't fix your issue please put a breakpoint in your success and error functions and let us know what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the backend is working properly, the ng-model you're using and the value you're appending to your query string are not the same. You have ng-model="id" but you're using $scope.Id in your query string build.

You need to use the same capitalization on both, whether it is $scope.id and ng-model="id", or both with a capital I.

Comment: i mead this changes i also got the result but not on the ng-blur event, i am create the new button then i call the function, then got the result but on want the data on the textbox on blur even , i does not want more button there..

Comment: In your code above, you have the ngBlur INSIDE you type="text" tag. That needs to be type="text" ng-blur="dataTest()". And if the answer above solved your initial problem, please accept the answer as correct.